# How to implement iOS DeviceCheck in PHP - problem signing JWT token with existing private key

Tags: php, ios, laravel, symfony, jwt

Have been trying to implement Devicecheck for iOS. This should be straightforward as I have this guide to follow:

https://fluffy.es/devicecheck-tutorial/#jwt

And I just need to convert the given Ruby code into PHP.

Tried using openssl but seemed that EC keys weren't supported. I got the error 'key type not supported in this PHP build!'.

So I turned to the JWT Framework.

I can create a EC key as per:

https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/components/key-jwk-and-key-set-jwkset/key-management#elliptic-curve-key-pair

but I can't figure out how to pass the pre-existing private key value (from Apple) to it, as in the Ruby example.

This is my code so far:

```
public function jwtToken()
{
    $private_key = env('DEVICE_CHECK_KEY_STRING');
    $key_id = env('DEVICE_CHECK_KEY_ID');
    $team_id = env('DEVICE_CHECK_TEAM_ID');

    $algorithmManager = AlgorithmManager::create([
        new ES256()
    ]);

    $jwk = JWKFactory::createECKey('P-256');

    $jsonConverter = new StandardConverter();

    $jwsBuilder = new JWSBuilder(
        $jsonConverter,
        $algorithmManager
    );

    $payload = $jsonConverter->encode([
        'iss' => $team_id,
        'iat' => time()
    ]);

    $jws = $jwsBuilder
            ->create()
            ->withPayload($payload)
            ->addSignature($jwk, ['alg' => 'ES256', 'kid' => $key_id])
            ->build();

    $serializer = new CompactSerializer($jsonConverter);

    $token = $serializer->serialize($jws, 0);

    return $token;
}
```

This will generate a JWT token but I don't get how I'm supposed to factor in the existing private key.

Comment: have you tried JS for encryption?